# Why does Visual Studio break System.Net.Socket with each different user session?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sockets, system.net.sockets

I know that I don't have a normal setup, but here it is:

I work in a computer lab, and the computers run on a disk image using Deep Freeze and

Each time you login to Windows 7, I believe that it is initialized each login; user settings are not retained after logout.

1. I create a new C# 4.0 Console Application Project in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
2. I paste the following code:

   ```
   using System.Net.Sockets;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Ctrl+Shift+S
4. F5; it runs through and terminates without any errors.
5. I logout of Windows and login again.
6. Open project in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
7. F5; Argument Exception: http://pastebin.com/pSju1p76

   ```
   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
     Message=An invalid argument was supplied
     Source=System
     ErrorCode=10022
     NativeErrorCode=10022
   ```

What's up with this?

Comment: Without the details of the exception it feels pointless to post it here... Why tomorrow? Why not now?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pSju1p76 << error